# How to generate rollback tags using liquibase API

Tags: java, liquibase

How would I use the liquibase API to generate changelogs of a diff between two databases **including rollback tags**.

My code currently looks like this

```
    CompareControl compareControl = new CompareControl();
    DiffResult diffResult = liquibase.diff(referenceDatabase,
                    siteDatabase, compareControl);

    // Output the diff
    DiffOutputControl diffOutputControl = new DiffOutputControl(
                    Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE);
    new DiffToChangeLog(diffResult, diffOutputControl)
                    .print(diffChangelogFile);
```

And it works fine, but I need it to include the rollback statements as well. 
I wasnt able to see anything related in CompareControl or DiffOutputControl classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'rollback tags' you mean the `<rollback></rollback>` tags in the changelog XML, there is not any way to get to those by doing a diff between two databases. During a normal deploy, nothing from those tags is written to the database.